# Synchronization on boxed primitive

Tags: java, multithreading, findbugs

I am new to multithreaded programming. So I need some help to this issue. I get a findbugs bug with synchronization on a boxed primitive:

http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DL_SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_BOXED_PRIMITIVE

I tried some solutions on this site but it doesn't work as I expected. Sometimes I get a similar error from findbugs.

My code needs a lock on a id which I pass to a constructor, here is some pseudocode:

```
public class MyClass{
   public MyClass(long id){
      synchronized(id){
         // do some stuff
      }    
   }
}
```

The problem is, that only threads with the same id should block on the synchronized block. Threads with different ids should work simultaneously.

I also tried something like this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
public class MyClass{

   private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Object> myHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Object>();

   public MyClass(long id){

      Object object = getObject(id);

      synchronized(object){
         // do some stuff
      }    
   }

   private Object getObject(long id){
      if(!myHashMap.contains(id)){
         writeObject(id);
      }
      return myHashMap.get(id);
   }

   private synchronized void writeObject(long id){
      if(!myHashMap.contains(id)){
          myHashMap.put(id, new Object());
      }
   }
}
```

In the second example you see, I tried to put an object per id in the hashmap, but with 
an unit test I realized, that threads with same id get in the synchronized block. But they should not do. I will be very thankful if someone has another solution or how to handle these problems.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is this some sort of cache? Can you show your unit test? (Your second approach looks OK except that the get method is not atomic and the put method is synchronized which does not make sense).

Comment: I try to lock on an object per id, that means if a thread with id=1 enters the synchronized block it should exclude all other threads with id=1. But threads with different ids can work parallel. The problem is, as I mentioned, that primitive types and boxed primitives in JVM uses (somehow) same instances and thats dangerous. That means locking on primitive or boxed primitve can result that threads with same id=1 can enter the critical section.

Comment: How do you know that different threads with the same ID are in the critical section at once? Are you sure it isn't an error in your test code?

Comment: In my JVM my test works for primitive values. So I tested with the primitive and with the object. The first solution worked for me and my test didn't fail. But the second solution failed. I did some output to see if the HashMap is correct which I created. It looked very good with one instance to every id. I will post the code or parts of it as soon as I can.

Comment: My files looks like this: https://gist.github.com/okarahan/d01203e65d0a11ec6cb9 and this: https://gist.github.com/okarahan/df20f154bc6c29a49965

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good for you that you wrote an unit test! For future reference: You want to test all kinds of edge values, which means for numbers at least 0, -1, 1, MAX_VALUE, MIN_VALUE - that would've caught the second bug you missed :-)

The problem with your code is that: `synchronized(l) {}` translates to: `synchronized(Long.valueOf(l)){}`. `valueOf` caches Longs in the range -128, 127 but even this is *optional* (the JLS only requires it for  integers surprisingly!). Consequently as soon as your ids are larger than 127 your whole scheme falls apart.

Your second method is the way to go, but you cannot just make the method synchronized - that will just synchronize on `this`, so doesn't guarantee atomicity for the static map.

Instead do something like this:

```
Object newLock = new Object();
Object oldLock = map.putIfAbsent(id, newLock);
Object lock = oldLock != null ? oldLock : newLock;
synchronized(lock) { 

}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than mine.

Comment: Err, putIfAbsent() returns null if there was no mapping for the key.

Comment: @JB Oh right, so much for actually remembering the API. Makes actually more sense. Thanks fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day :) I think thats the way to go.

Comment: “the JLS only requires it for integers surprisingly”— actually it surprised me that it has such a hard requirement at all when I first read the JLS for Java 5. Normally it only *recommends* to do the best when it comes to performance. And maintaining a global cache is not always better than creating a temporary object that doesn’t escape…

Comment: @Holger Well I *knew* that it required it for Integers already, so the surprise was more that it did for ints but not longs.